# How to display the row value in a column into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012-express

I have a few rows in a column as below:

```
Country
----------
 USA
 UK
 Singapore
```

Now, I want to have result as below exactly:

```
First_Country |  Second_Country |  Third_Country
--------------+-----------------+--------------
 USA          |   UK            |   Singapore
 NULL         |   USA           |   UK
```

How to do? I tried `Pivot` or `Unpivot` no luck.

Comment: Please provide output sample in exact tabular form you want it to be.

Comment: @KasimHusaini: Thanks, now it is in correct format. Please help. I am using 2008 Management Studio. Is there simple way to do in 2012?

Comment: How do you determine which row gets grouped with which other rows? There needs to be another column to determine the groups of rows to pivot. Grouping without it would probably be possible but totally arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Query to achieve this:

```
select  GROUP_CONCAT(<Column_Name> SEPARATOR ' ') from <Table_Name>;
```

Where,
Column_Name - Column you would want to concat into single result
Table_Name - Table which has the above column.

Comment: Janakiraman, thank you, however, it says GROUP_CONCAT is not a recognized function. I am using 2008 Management Studio. Please help. Is this dependent on Version?

Comment: The Above query is specific  to MySQL. For SQL Server you can use something like this:SELECT STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + Column_Name 
              FROM Table_Name
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '')

Comment: Janakiraman, thank you, this query looks better. But, is it possible to have it in different column as I given the output above in my question? 2nd Row should have NULL in the first column

Comment: on what basis the second row has null value?